# IE8 conditional javascript not linking

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors, selectivizr

here's a landing page I've coded up:

http://rsa-partner.com/

It all looks fine in every browser bar IE8. In IE8, the advanced CSS selector 'nth child' is not recognised.

I downloaded and linked selectivizr.js (http://selectivizr.com/), which should have sorted it in ie, but alas, the background images that show on all my nth child selectors are not showing. The code is

```
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/selectivizr-min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Is there something I'm missing? I swear I've used conditional IE specific comments before and got nothing back. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Of course I could simply remove my nth child selectors and replace with specific classes but I'd like to avoid that if possible!

Comment: That conditional statement does look hinky ?

Comment: If you want to target only IE 8, why not use `<!--[if IE 8]>`?

Comment: Isn't that "greater than IE6 and lower than IE8" ??

Comment: @adeneo: I think it is >= IE 6 and <= IE 8. For OR it is |, so i guess & should work for AND.

Comment: Anyway, who cares about IE < 6? Just do `IE lte 8`

Comment: @Harry - indeed, `gte` is "greater than **or** equal", just `gt` would be "greater than", can never remember this crap, as it's been years since I used it last.

Comment: Found this [link](http://segfaultlabs.com/devlogs/not-only-internet-explorer-conditional-comments) and the condition seems fine.

Comment: Your syntax is fine based on this [resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx). I'd check the following limitations mentioned for `selectivizr` though http://selectivizr.com/#things

Comment: You're sure the issue isn't elsewhere. IE8 has issues with empty elements etc. and you're elements doesn't look like they have any content, just a background image, and you're using display inline, floats etc. Lots of things that could cause issues in IE8 ?

Comment: I'm guessing you got this fixed? I don't see a difference in IE8 as of now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your content is loaded in dynamically (like if you are using a CMS system), then it gets loaded after Selectivizr is run, and therefore it won't work.

From [selectivzr.com](http://selectivizr.com/):

> The emulation is not dynamic. Once the styles are applied they are fixed so changes to the DOM won't be reflected.

I recommend using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/#-shiv-cssclasses-teststyles-testprop-testallprops-prefixes-domprefixes-css_lastchild-load) instead. You can check for `css-lastchild` and customize the styles if the browser doesn't support it (together with the rest of the CSS3 selectors, like `nth-child`, etc.). I share your pain though!